# Find $\mathrm {E} (X), \mathrm {Var} (X)$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expectation, variance

> > A sample of size $n$ is drawn from $\{1,2, \cdots , N \}$ with replacement. Let $X$ denote the minimum of the numbers drawn. Calculate
> >
> > $(a)$ the  PMF of $X,$
> >
> > $(b)$ $\mathrm E (X),$
> >
> > $(c)$ $\mathrm {Var} (X),$
> >
> > $(d)$ If $Y$ denotes the maximum of the numbers drawn$,$ calculate the joint PMF of $X$ and $Y$.

I have found

$$P(X=k)= \frac {(N-k+1)^n - (N-k)^n} {N^n}.$$

But this isn't much helpful in calculating the expectation and variance of the random variable $X$. So how should I proceed in this regard? Please help me.

Thank you very much.

I have found the joint probability of the random variables $X$ and $Y$ as follows $:$

$$P(X=i,Y=j) =  \frac {(j-i+1)^n - 2(j-i)^n+(j-i-1)^n} {N^n}.$$ for $i=1,2,\cdots,N$ and $j=1,2,,\cdots,N$.

Is it correct? Please verify it.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer for part (a) is correct.

For part (b), write your result from part (a) as

$$\mathsf P(X\gt k)=\frac{(N-k)^n}{N^n}$$

and calculate

$$
\mathsf E(X)=\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\mathsf P(X\gt k)=\sum_{k=1}^N\frac{k^n}{N^n}\;,
$$

which can be evaluated using [Faulhaber's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula). Approximating the sum by an integral for large $N$ yields the approximation $E(X)\approx\frac N{n+1}$.

For part (c), use the fact that the variance of the minimum is the variance of the maximum to transform to $j=N-k+1$, which leads to $j^n-(j-1)^n$ in the numerator; then use $j=(j-1)+1$ as appropriate to write the expectation of $j^2$ in terms of sums of powers of $j$.

Your answer for part (d) is correct; it was recently asked about in 
[Calculating probability of High+Low = T on N dice with S sides](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2865527).